# Delayed Postgresql Backup table

Tags: postgresql

Is there an easy way to create a replica table on the same postgresql server that is delayed by 24 hours?

I have tried creating a cron that does an insert with a command like this

```
INSERT INTO TABLE_BACKUP
SELECT * from TABLE_new WHERE time< (NOW() - INTERVAL '1 day');
```

I have found that doing the above some records are missing.

Is there a better way?

Comment: What PostgreSQL Version are you using? Also, what are the requirement for the replica table? Must deletes and updates be replicated to?

Comment: Hi, version 9.3 and all data that is in TABLE X must be in TABLE Y but delayed by 24 hours

Comment: I think there is no way to accomplish that without any third party tools or complex triggers. In PostgreSQL 9.4 you could use a delayed replicated standby server, but 9.3 does not have this feature. Also, 9.3 will be EOL by September of this year